# Библиотека Telegram - программное закрытие сессий

Tags: api, telegram

Хочу автоматизировать закрытие всех сессий (кроме, естественно текущей) Telegram в автоматическом режиме (по наступлению какого-либо события).
Подскажите, какая библиотека (C#/Java) реализует функции API Telegram (**НЕ Bot-API, а именно  Telegram-api**)?
Посмотрел

1. https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramApi
2. https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp

Но в них, видимо, не реализован такой функционал...

Answer (score 1):

API Telegram предоставляет метод [auth.resetAuthorizations](https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.resetAuthorizations) для закрытия всех сессий кроме текущей. И как минимум названная вами библиотека [TelegramApi](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramApi) его поддерживает, так как данный метод [прописан в схеме поддерживаемых ей запросов](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramApi/blob/d0d97a029e665f91ad2febfa9d86c5ab05088750/src/main/resources/schema.txt#L755).